# marker and polyline in flutter google map

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-maps

hello i'am new with flutter and i have a probelm with google map
when i tap for the second time  on the map to set the destination marker and obtain the polyline and direction i got nothing i can only set the source marker
also when i search for places in the searche bar nothing happend
the is my code

```
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  TextEditingController _originController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _destinationController = TextEditingController();

  Set<Marker> _markers = Set<Marker>();
  Set<Polygon> _polygons = Set<Polygon>();
  List<LatLng> _polygonLatLngs = <LatLng>[];
  Set<Polyline> _polylines = Set<Polyline>();

  int _polygonIdCounter = 1;
  int _polylineIdCounter = 1;

  static final CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(36.27921023154921, 6.58817705266346),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _setMarker(LatLng(36.27921023154921, 6.58817705266346));
  }

  void _setMarker(LatLng point) {
    setState(() {
      _markers.add(
        Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId('Marker'),
          position: point,
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

this polyline void

```
 void _setPolyline(List<PointLatLng> points) {
    final String polylineIdVal = "polyline_$_polylineIdCounter";
    _polylineIdCounter++;
    _polylines.add(Polyline(
      polylineId: PolylineId(polylineIdVal),
      width: 2,
      color: Colors.blue,
      points: points
          .map(
            (point) => LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude),
          )
          .toList(),
    ));
```

the google map widget

```
    child: GoogleMap(
      myLocationEnabled: true,
      myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      markers: _markers,
      polygons: _polygons,
      polylines: _polylines,
      initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
        _controller.complete(controller);
      },
      onTap: (point) {
        setState(() {
          _polygonLatLngs.add(point);
          _setPolygon();
          _markers.add(
              Marker(markerId: MarkerId('Marker'), position: point));

        });
      },
    ),
```

my location services

```
import 'package:flutter_polyline_points/flutter_polyline_points.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert' as convert;
class LocationService {
  final String key = 'my api key';

  Future<String> getPlaceId(String input) async {
    final String url =
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=$input&inputtype=textquery&key=$key";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var json = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
    var placeId = json["candidates"][0]["place_id"] as String;
    // print(placeId);
    return (placeId);
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getPlace(String input) async {
    final placeId = await getPlaceId(input);

    final String url =
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=$placeId&key=$key";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var json = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
    var results = json["result"] as Map<String, dynamic>;
    print(results);
    return (results);
  }

  Future <Map <String, dynamic>> getDirection(String origin, String destination) async {
    final String url =
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=$origin&destination=$destination&key=$key";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var json = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
    var results = {
      'bounds_ne': json["routes"] [0] ['bounds'] ["northeast"],
      "bounds_sw": json ["routes"] [0] ['bounds'] ["southwest"],
      'start_location': json ["routes"] [0] ['legs'] [0] ["start_location"],
      "end_location":json ["routes"] [0] ['legs'] [0] ["end_location"],
      'polyline': json ["routes"] [0] ['overview_polyline'] ["points"],
      'polyline_decoded':PolylinePoints().decodePolyline(json ["routes"] [0] ['overview_polyline']  ["points"],),
          };
    print(results);
    return(results);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

### add Package

```
flutter_polyline_points: ^1.0.0
```

```
polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(polyLines.values),  
Map<PolylineId, Polyline> polyLines = {};
```

```
  polyLineDraw() async {
    List<Marker> markers = [];
    List<AudioMapModel> _tempListAudio = Provider.of<MapAudioViewModel>(context, listen: false).audioMapModelList;
    PolylinePoints _polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();
    List<LatLng> _polylineCoordinates = [];
    for(int i=0;i<_tempListAudio.length;i++){
      markers.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(i.toString()),
          position: _tempListAudio[i].latLng,
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(
              title: _tempListAudio[i].name
          )
      ));
    }
    for(int i=0;i<markers.length;i++){
      await _polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
        'YourGoogleAPIKey',
        PointLatLng(markers[i].position.latitude, markers[i].position.longitude),
        PointLatLng(markers[i+1].position.latitude, markers[i+1].position.longitude),
        travelMode: TravelMode.driving,
      )
          .then((value) {
        for (var point in value.points) {
          _polylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
        }
      }).then((value) {
        PolylineId id = PolylineId("poly$i");
        final Polyline polyline = Polyline(
            jointType: JointType.mitered,
            polylineId: id,
            width: 2,
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            points: _polylineCoordinates);
        polyLines[id] = polyline;
        setState(() {

        });
      });
    }
  }
```

```
    child: GoogleMap(
      myLocationEnabled: true,
      myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      markers: _markers,
      polygons: _polygons,
      polylines: polyLines,
      initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
    ),
```

Thanks Your Dear...

Comment: excuse me sir i didn't understand 
where should i put the "polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(polyLines.values),  
Map<PolylineId, Polyline> polyLines = {};"
and also the AudioMapModel show other errors 
thank you